# NodeJS CORS error when calling api from localhost Vue project

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express, cors

I have a project with a NodeJS/Express backend and a VueJS frontend. The problem I am facing is that I constantly get CORS errors:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:8080/api/plot. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

I have added the CORS middelware inside my index.js file of my NodeJS backend:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method',
  );
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
  res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
  next();
});
```

I also have tried a different approach:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
```

In the Vue project I have added the proxy to my vue.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    port: 8080,
    proxy: {
      '^/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        pathRewrite: { '^/api': '/api' },
        logLevel: 'debug',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Then I have changed the URL of my API call to post 8080:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const addPlot = async (plot) => {
  const url = `https://localhost:8080/api/plot`;
  return await axios.post(url, plot).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
};
```

[image]

Comment: It seems your Dev server is running on `http://localhost:8080/` and your are doing HTTPS request to the HTTP endpoint.

Comment: @MichalLevý The reason the requests are being send to 8080 is because of the proxy. This redirects all traffic that is being send to 3000 to port 8080. This should normally fix the CORS error.

Comment: I know. BUT port 8080 is HTTP (no SSL) and your are making your Axios call with HTTPS ....

Comment: @MichalLevý Thanks a lot! This fixed the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when you are using Webpack Dev server proxy, you don't need to configure Express with any CORS (assuming in production you are going to serve your Vue app build from the same Express server)

Reason why you getting CORS errors is that your app is served from `http://localhost:8080` (Webpack Dev server) but you are making your Axios request to `https://localhost:8080/api/plot` - important part is **HTTPS://** and because browser is using [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) only if protocol + host + port are all same, browser is firing CORS pre-flight request

Just make your Axios calls to HTTP instead of HTTPS and you should be fine...

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you processing preflight request (OPTIONS with empty 204 answer)
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request
2. Try to add **Access-Control-Expose-Headers** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

> allows a server to indicate which response headers should be made
> available to scripts running in the browser, in response to a
> cross-origin request

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I don't completely understand how I should do this?

Answer (score -1):

So a CORS error is basically a security error wherein browsers will not allow certain/most resources your project may need to be accepted from your server. You can handle it in two ways, and those two ways are dependent upon the environment of the server.

1. While in development, (www.localhost:port), you will need to install a library called cors (npm install cors) in your project folder. After which, you will need to import the library into your code. Thereafter, you will need to use the cors object as middleware (ps. I do not exactly know what middleware is - thanks to all the stackoverflow committee for their active answers). EXAMPLE:

   const express = require('express');
   const cors = require('cors');
   const app = express();

   app.use(cors())
   // app.get(....)
2. While in production, though, your cost-free options are limited. If you examine the error closely, the remarks state that cross resourcing is allowed for the https protocol (more, but not for http), so what is needed for your VPS is a Secure Socket Layer certificate, SSL certificate, which I bought for 8 dollars for a year. It is quite intimidating to acquire, but answers were never more than a few searches away, at maximum. Acquiring an SSL certificate requires a port forwarded IP address, so I would strongly suggest paying an extra 6 dollars a month to rent a VPS. Linode is offering some free credit, as of now, (not sponsored), so you might wanna rush. Anyway, steps for acquiring a certificate like this include installing OPENSSL, generating a Certificate Signing Request, (CSR), and then passing it on to your CA, after which you follow the steps they instruct you to follow, and then searching for instructions on using those certificates in your server. You guessed it - On Stackoverflow (:

For added instructions, please comment and I will try and answer.